# Does IP tables rules takes precedence over /proc/sys configuration?

Tags: security, iptables, proc

If I configure both Case 1 and Case 2 in the same Linux server, which case will take precedence over the other?

- Case 1 – `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all`
- Case 2 – iptables rules set to accept ICMP any to any

Comment: What stops you from trying?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 :

- echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all

Takes precedence over iptables rules.